# Cant run scm-server 2

Tags: scmmanager

I've downloaded scm-server 2 from Jenkins to run on my dedicated source code server. Unfortunately it won't start for some reason. It works on my desktop computer so probably there is just a package missing.

Using Ubuntu 18.04 with apache2 and jetty9 packages installed, which might be relevant.

Any ideas?

```
~/scm-server/bin$ ./scm-server
2019-09-16 10:33:58.689:INFO::main: Logging initialized @478ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2019-09-16 10:33:59.595:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.14.v20181114; built: 2018-11-14T21:20:31.478Z; git: c4550056e785fb5665914545889f21dc136ad9e6; jvm 12.0.2+10
2019-09-16 10:34:02.442:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /scm, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2019-09-16 10:34:02.514:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2019-09-16 10:34:02.516:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2019-09-16 10:34:02.525:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.ClassLoaderLeakPreventor (file:/home/klarre/scm-server/work/scm/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/classloader-leak-prevention-core-2.7.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.isAncestor(java.lang.ClassLoader)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.ClassLoaderLeakPreventor
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-09-16 10:34:04.105 [main] [          ] INFO  sonia.scm.lifecycle.BootstrapContextFilter - register for restart events
2019-09-16 10:34:04.125 [main] [          ] INFO  sonia.scm.event.LegmanScmEventBus - create new event bus ScmEventBus-1
2019-09-16 10:34:04.319:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4dc8caa7{SCM-Manager 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT,/scm,file:///home/klarre/scm-server/work/scm/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/klarre/scm-server/var/webapp/scm-webapp.war}
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: sonia.scm.event.ScmEventBus: Provider sonia.scm.event.LegmanScmEventBus could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:805)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:723)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1395)
    at sonia.scm.util.ServiceUtil.getService(ServiceUtil.java:99)
    at sonia.scm.event.ScmEventBus.getInstance(ScmEventBus.java:89)
    at sonia.scm.lifecycle.BootstrapContextFilter.initializeContext(BootstrapContextFilter.java:75)
    at sonia.scm.lifecycle.BootstrapContextFilter.init(BootstrapContextFilter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at sonia.scm.server.ScmServer.init(ScmServer.java:139)
    at sonia.scm.server.ScmServer.run(ScmServer.java:100)
    at sonia.scm.server.ScmServerDaemon.main(ScmServerDaemon.java:62)
Caused by: 
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.github.legman.HandlerFindingStrategy: service type not accessible to unnamed module @2c78d320
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:590)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.checkCaller(ServiceLoader.java:570)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.<init>(ServiceLoader.java:505)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.load(ServiceLoader.java:1647)
    at com.github.legman.internal.ServiceLocator.locate(ServiceLocator.java:67)
    at com.github.legman.internal.ServiceLocator.locate(ServiceLocator.java:92)
    at com.github.legman.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:152)
    at sonia.scm.event.LegmanScmEventBus.create(LegmanScmEventBus.java:79)
    at sonia.scm.event.LegmanScmEventBus.<init>(LegmanScmEventBus.java:73)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:781)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:723)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1395)
    at sonia.scm.util.ServiceUtil.getService(ServiceUtil.java:99)
    at sonia.scm.event.ScmEventBus.getInstance(ScmEventBus.java:89)
    at sonia.scm.lifecycle.BootstrapContextFilter.initializeContext(BootstrapContextFilter.java:75)
    at sonia.scm.lifecycle.BootstrapContextFilter.init(BootstrapContextFilter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at sonia.scm.server.ScmServer.init(ScmServer.java:139)
    at sonia.scm.server.ScmServer.run(ScmServer.java:100)
    at sonia.scm.server.ScmServerDaemon.main(ScmServerDaemon.java:62)
2019-09-16 10:34:04.377:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2019-09-16 10:34:04.382:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@53d102a2{/,[file:///home/klarre/scm-server/var/webapp/docroot/],AVAILABLE}
2019-09-16 10:34:04.459:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@18c49a9f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8088}
2019-09-16 10:34:04.460:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @6303ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing from openjdk-12 to openjdk-8 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Took some time, but from version 2.0.0-rc4 on, SCM-Manager is compatible with Java 9 and above.

Here you can find out how to get the version: https://www.scm-manager.org/uncategorized/scm-manager-2-0-0-rc4/